Why are separate subdomains used in for tracking and hosting on Marketing Automation platforms?
I have used a variety of marketing automation platforms (Marketo, SalesForce Marketing Cloud, etc.) and I have noticed that it's nearly universal that links used for tracking use one subdomain (e.g. trk.example.com) while images uploaded to the platform are hosted on another subdomain (img.example.com). I'm hoping to gain more insight into this practice.
Is there a reason why a single subdomain is not used for both purposes?

I don't think this can be definitvely answered, but I expect it is to easily segregate different business units - guys doing analytics typically won't have much to do with running the site - likewise servers used for analytics will have different characteristics to main servers.  Also if they want to spin off the Analytics business its easy to do.

Aside from the valid reasons david mentioned, I would imagine it makes it less likely a website's functionality could be broken by ad blockers. If the hosting domain is well-behaved, ad blockers may block the tracking domain while leaving the hosting domain untouched.

It's quite simple. Essentially, all the commentators are right:
Companies use this method to protect the reputation of the main domain. Since tracking links can be flagged as spam, there is a risk of sanctions against the domain, such as blacklisting or blocks.
The second point is functional separation — this makes it easier to track web traffic, and the modules are isolated from each other. If one goes down, the other keeps running.
Additionally, it’s about load distribution. Some servers handle static content, while others process redirects and are tied to analytics.
